# how to insert different information without deleting the previous one in firebase, react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i dont know how to insert different information without deleting the previous one in firebase
i have this:

```
static setNombre(userId, typedNombre){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/titulo"
    return firebase.database().ref(userNamePath).set(typedNombre)
}
static setPrecio(userId, typedPrecio){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/precio"
    return firebase.database().ref(userNamePath).set(typedPrecio)
}
static setDescribcion(userId, typedDescribcion){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/descripcion"
    return firebase.database().ref(userNamePath).set(typedDescribcion)
}
static setLugar(userId, typedLugar){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/Lugar"
    return firebase.database().ref(userNamePath).set(typedLugar)
}
static setNota(userId, typedNota){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/nota"
    return firebase.database().ref(userNamePath).set(typedNota)
}
```

and in my database i have this

[image]

but when i insert other information with the same user, the information in firebase overwrite

and what I want is that, when I insert other information that's kept that

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your database structure.

Comment: sorry I already corrected it.

Comment: you will need to generate random keys for each name or price, or even create subchilds inside Prodductos with different names

Comment: ooo thaks yes i do whith push() function, thaks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `set()` on a reference, the new data you specify replaces the existing data at that location. To keep the existing data and update it, you should use `update()`:

```
static setNombre(userId, typedNombre){
    let userNamePath = "/user/"+userId+"/Productos/titulo"
    return firebase.database().update({ userNamePath: typedNombre })
}
```

This code will leave everything at the root intact and will only replace the value at `/user/.../Productos/titulo`.